# How can I update the value of an attribute through trigger right after insertion into that table?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

This the table that I have.

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
employee_id VARCHAR(10) null,
employee_email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
employee_first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
employee_last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE (employee_id));
```

This is the trigger that I'm using.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger employee_id_update_trigger
after insert on employees
   for each row  
        begin
           update employees set new.employee_id= concat('ecl-emp-',id) 
           where id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
        end$$ 
delimiter ;
```

This is the insertion that I'm trying to do.

```
INSERT INTO `employees` 
VALUES (1,null,'abc@gmail.com','ABC','DEF');
```

The error that I'm getting is given below.

```
11:29:16    INSERT INTO `employees`  VALUES  (1,null,'abc@gmail.com','ABC','DEF')   Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'employees' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. 1.282 sec
```

Comment: Showing that same error after replacing before with after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to actually run an `update` statement if you just want to change the values before the `insert`. You should just be able to use `set`. Even if it worked, I'm not sure your attempt using `LAST_INSERT_ID` would be safe if there were a lot of inserts happening concurrently.

I think your syntax should be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER employee_id_update_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON employees
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.employee_id=concat('ecl-emp-',NEW.id);
```

or

```
delimiter $$
create trigger employee_id_update_trigger
before insert on employees
   for each row  
        begin
           SET NEW.employee_id=concat('ecl-emp-',NEW.id);
        end$$ 
delimiter ;
```

See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) for more examples.